# How to I set a readonly variable in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, readonly

I know how to set a readonly variable in a normal class, but how do I set one in a page?

What I want to do is read the querystring and fix the variable.

Is this even possible in a page?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose not!

You can always use Hidden Values for the same, till you don't change it will be ReadOnly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use the `Object.freeze()` method defined in the ECMAScript spec 5.1. It prevents an object from being changed (for the most part; the object's values that are also objects can still be changed, unless frozen as well). You can [read up on it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). All major browsers support it, with Microsoft having implemented it in IE 9+.

Another method would be to have a querystring value for the variable you want, as well as another querystring value that contains the has for your variable and another known, constant value. You can then hash both those pieces of data to ensure that the user hasn't tampered with the querystring value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read-only variable in C# on page load and initialize it on page load.

```
readonly string urlValue=Request.QueryString["yourparameter"];
```

But after the post-back it will re-initilize.